# Emberjs sort hasMany association as a computed property

Tags: ember.js, associations, has-many, computed-properties

I have two models, folder and files.  A folder has many files.  If I say `folder.get('files')` I get all the files associated with that folder ordered by id.  I would like the array of files to be order by something other then the id; lets say createDate.  If possible, I do not want to make a computed property that has a different name then `files`.

Any help would greatly be appreciated?

Comment: Why are you not defining `files` as computed property that depends on some filter value and when no filter value is set it orders by id as default.

Comment: because I do not know how to do that.  :-)

Comment: It would help to show what you have tried so far and maybe to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you need to create an computed property `files` in your controller, which contains your sorting logic.

```
files: function() {
  var filter = this.get('filter');
  return this.get('model').sortBy(filter);
}.property('filter')
```

Here is a JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pojaxikayu/3/edit, demonstrating how it works. The example is very basic and should be extended according to your specific needs.

You also can use [`Ember.SortableMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) in you controller. Here is the example from above using the mixin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hebisorexo/2/edit