# Emberjs advanced sort hasMany association as a computed property

Tags: sorting, ember.js, has-many, computed-properties

I have asked a variant of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691579/emberjs-sort-hasmany-association-as-a-computed-property).  But basically I need to create a computed property that operated on a hasMany association.  I need to do sorting similar to the javascript [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function; where I can do something like

```
files = ["File 5", "File 1", "File 3", "File 2"];
files.sort(function(a,b){
  return parseInt(b.split(' ').pop()) - parseInt(a.split(' ').pop())
});
```

result:

```
["File 5", "File 3", "File 2", "File 1"]
```

Here is my jsbin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/simayexose/edit?html,js,output

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note:
My jsbin presently is not working correctly (for reasons other then this question).  I have posted a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926167/emberjs-fixtures-are-not-showing-up-in-jsbin).  I just did not want to hold up an answer to this question.

## Update 1

Thanks @engma.  I implemented the instructions.  As a matter of fact, I copied and pasted what was posted.  This is the new jsbin.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/roqixemuyi/1/edit?html,js,output

I still do not get anything sorted, though.  And even if it did, it still would not have sorted the way I would like it.

I need something like the following: (below are errors that I get when I try to implement this in my code, not from jsbin, since I can not get jsbin to work)

```
  sortedFiles: function(){
    return this.get('files').sort(function(a,b){
      return parseInt(b.split(' ').pop()) - parseInt(a.split(' ').pop());
    });
  }.property('files.@each.name')
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).sort is not a function
```

So since `this.get('files')` returns a promise, I figured I would try this;

```
  sortedFiles: function(){
    return this.get('files').then(function(files){
      return files.sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(b.split(' ').pop()) - parseInt(a.split(' ').pop());
      });
    });
  }.property('files.@each.name')
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 243, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: }
```

BTW, I am using emberjs v1.11.0

And, the sortBy I am using is `ember-cli/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/mout/array/sortBy.js`

Here is the code for it

```
var sort = require('./sort');
var makeIterator = require('../function/makeIterator_');

    /*
     * Sort array by the result of the callback
     */
    function sortBy(arr, callback, context){
        callback = makeIterator(callback, context);

        return sort(arr, function(a, b) {
            a = callback(a);
            b = callback(b);
            return (a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0);
        });
    }

    module.exports = sortBy;
```

## Update 2

So to answer the question how to do an Emberjs advanced sort hasMany association as a computed property; I had to change

```
  this.get('files').sort(function(a,b){
      ...
  });

  return this.get('files').toArray().sort(function(a,b){
    ...
  });
```

This allowed me to use the javascript sort and return the desired sorted objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all your JSBin had many issues so lets go throw them one by one

1- you did not include any Ember-Data build, so I included 1, this is needed for the fixtures and the models

```
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.15/ember-data.js"></script>
```

2- Your Scripts

```
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create({
});
//First this is how to register the adapter
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //Second with find you pass in the ID so I am using 1
    //if you want to get all folders use findAll()
    return this.store.find('folder',1);
  } 
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});


App.Router.map(function() {
});

App.Folder = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  files:  DS.hasMany('file',{async:true}),
  sortedFiles: function(){
    //Sorty By has no second parameter, if you need more sorting power, do it your self
    return this.get('files').sortBy('name');
  }.property('files.@each.name')

});

App.File = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  folder: DS.belongsTo('folder',{async:true})
});

App.File.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'File 5',
    folder:1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'File 1',
    folder:1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'File 3',
    folder:1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'File 2',
    folder:2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'File 6',
    folder:2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'File 4',
    folder:2
  }
];


App.Folder.FIXTURES = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files:[1,2,3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files:[4,5,6]
  }
];
```

Your Template:

```
<div>
   Folders: <br>
  <ul>
   <li>
     Name: {{model.name}} <br>
     Files:
     {{!-- here we access the sorted files property in the model--}}
     {{#each file in model.sortedFiles}}
       {{file.name}} <br/>
     {{/each}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was going through so many ember jsbins I must have forgot that Ember-Data.  I updated my jsbin.  It did not really change anything though.  `sortedFiles: function(){
    //Sorty By has no second parameter, if you need more sorting power, do it your self
    return this.get('files').sortBy('name');
  }.property('files.@each.name')` is where I have my issue.  I believe the version of emberjs I am using has sortBy taking multiple arguments.  But even if I do not use sortBy, when I use the regular sort function, I do not get files ordered.  Nothing gets displayed.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer, since you did direct me to do the sorting 'myself' if I needed more sorting power as oppose to using sortBy.  However, my last update to the question allowed me to use the default javascript sort, and thus do it 'myself'.  If you do not mind, please comment on how I can get your code I copied and pasted to work on jsbin.  Or, please take a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926167/emberjs-fixtures-are-not-showing-up-in-jsbin and let me know how to get fixtures working on jsbin.  Thanks again.

Comment: very sorry for the late response, here is the my jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/banozisuqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output